# Precedence rules

Tags: first-order-logic

From my understanding

1. $P \land Q \lor R$ should be understood as $((P \land Q) \lor R)$ due to the precedence-rules and
2. $\exists x Px \land Qx$ should be understood as $(\exists x Px \land Qx)$ and not $\exists x (Px \land Qx)$ as the scope of $\exists$ is just $x$.

But how do you express this meaningful if you combine the two rules in an example? I would think that $\exists x P(x) \land Q(x) \lor R(x)$ is $(\exists x ((P(x) \land Q(x)) \lor R(x)))$, but that conflicts "rule 2" above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The, in my impression, most common convention (but your textbook may define it differently, so check the syntax definitions there) is that quantifiers have precedence over all connectives:

1. $\forall$, $\exists$
2. $\neg$
3. $\land$
4. $\lor$
5. $\to$
6. $\leftrightarrow$

From this your second bullet point ($\exists$ having precedence over $\land$) would automatically follow, and in addition that $\exists$ precedes $\lor$.

So
$\exists x P(x) \land Q(x) \lor R(x)\\  
= (\exists x P(x)) \land Q(x) \lor R(x) \quad (\exists > \land, \lor)\\
= ((\exists x P(x)) \land Q(x)) \lor R(x) \quad (\land > \lor).$

In general, combining two precedence rules amounts to simply merging the orders they prescribe into one:
(1) "$\land$" > "$\lor$" +  (2) "$\exists$ > "$\land$"
= "$\exists$" > "$\land$" > "$\lor$"

Comment: Thanks a lot! Makes sense! I have tried to build it from the lowest precedence in stead of the highest. Your approach made things clear for me. But wouldn't your first step limit the scope of $\exists x$ to $P(x)$ only, and not Qx and Rx?

Comment: Yes, the first step limits the scope of $\exists x$ to $P(x)$ only -- hence why $\exists x P(x)$ is bracketed, and $Q(x) \lor R(x)$ is outside those brackets, meaning that it is not in the scope of $\exists x$. (Possibly even bracketing definitions to indicate scope differ; it can be a bit of a mess.)

Comment: To make it even clearer: $... = ((\exists x (P(x))) \land Q(x)) \lor R(x)$.

Comment: Thanks! To me that made it even clearer. A glimpse of insight in a foggy mess of conventions. As a side note I can't understand why there are several conventions around. Is it because of the variance in computer applications of the formulas?

Comment: I'd say mostly it's a historical accident, different conventions developed in parallel and there never really was a universally agreed on definition, and not a strict need to because in case of doubt one can (should) always define it and often it is clear from context which bracketing is likely intended.

Comment: Partially it's also a matter of taste or purpose. For example, as for associativity, i.e. left vs. right prec. between the same type of connective, it is more usual to assume that formulas are built up such that new stuff is appended to the right of existing fml.s, which leads to left associativity, i.e. to e.g. read $p \to q \to r$ as $((p \to q) \to r)$. But for implicative statements, it is somehow more intuitive to read $p \to q \to r$ as $(p \to (q \to r))$ because this is a formula scheme that more usually naturally needs, so this would be a reason to define associativity to the right.